# How to export a specific registry key to a text file using command line

Tags: command-line, windows-registry

How can I export specific value from the registry to a text file using the command line?

For example, I want to export `Hkey_local_Machine\Software\mcafee` to a text file in C:.
I just need the key – that's it.

I tried with `reg export` – it's giving everything, but I just require the key of the partiular thing.

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow what you actually want to export.  What do you mean by `reg export` "giving everything"?  Did you specify the exact key you wanted to export?

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
reg export Hkey_local_Machine\Software\mcafee C:\export.txt
```

This will export registry values according to windows REG format.

Answer (score 4):

You can export a specific registry value to a *text* file with a [setx command](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)
Copy/pasta from there:

```
SetX _TZone /k HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\StandardName
>Tzone.txt echo %_TZone%
```

The alternative to above is to write it to a [*reg*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc742017.aspx) file using the methods in the above answers:

```
REG EXPORT HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\StandardName C:\Windows\Temp\Tzone.reg
```

The reg file can be opened for read/write, check [here](http://help.globalscape.com/help/eft6/Creating_a_.reg_File.htm) for format.

Comment: Never heard of `SETX` but it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> reg export Hkey_local_Machine\Software\mcafee\key C:\export.txt && type C:\export.txt | findstr /i "key"

Comment: Hey this looks kinda like what I'm looking for. can I export all keys containing "specialString" by using `reg export C:\export.reg findstr /i "specialString"`?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes one has to enclose the registry key in quotes in order to get down to individual items

REG EXPORT "HKCU\Software\SS64\xxxx" C:\MyReg.REG

Comment: Not working while it has white space (ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.)

Answer (score 0):

Enter this in at the *DOS* prompt :

> `reg export HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall test.txt && type test.txt | findstr /i "DisplayName" > list.txt | notepad list.txt`

Comment: Please consider using ``` to mark your command line as code. In addition consider adding an explanation of how it works so it would be clearer on how to adapt it to the original question.